# Is in .NET Core something similar to ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-core, activerecord

I am switching from Rails to .NET Core, but what I really miss is ActiveRecord ORM. In models you just define relationship:

```
#Town Model
class Town < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
end

#Country Model
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :towns
end
```

Then you can simple obtain list of all Towns in specific Country:

```
@country = Country.find(params[:id])
@towns = @country.towns
```

That's very clear, especially in situations, where u are chaining multiple models over ids. In .Net Core i usually end up on something like this:

```
Task<List<Town>> towns = await _context.Towns.Where(x => x.CountryId == countryId).ToListAsync();
```

That's still acceptable, but only because there is only model - model relationship.

Lets say we want to obtain Continent of selected Town in Rails:

```
@town = Town.find(params[:id])
@continent = @town.country.continent
```

In .NET Core, now I have to work with Joins and final result will be quite complex, its easy to do mistake here (and its not even complex situation). Image having very complex SQL query, LINQ doesnt help u much and u are very close to writing pure SQL.

That's why I ask, if is in .NET Core something similar to very handy ActiveRecord ORM in Rails.

Thanks for your reply and time.

Comment: EF supports [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) out of the box, so in simple situations you don't need joins. Also you can use [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) if you want to.

Comment: Can u explain it little bit more? I am using data configuration with FluentAPI (Ef core), but main purpose is to create db structure and define relationship. But it doesnt allow u to use simplified queries (or i dont know about that).

Comment: Please add you entities and configuration

Comment: It is no specific problem question, I ask in general. If there is better approach in .net core show it on above example with continent - country - town.

Comment: What is wrong with `await _context.Towns.Where(x => x.CountryId == countryId).ToListAsync()` ? Also there is [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-3.1) method, though it will be less performant due to boxing.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, its just long. And it become much more longer, when u jump into more complex queries - you can do much more mistakes compered to Rails ActiveRecord, which is really short, simple. That's why I ask for something similar in .Net Core.

Comment: Please show the example of "complex" query. Cause what you have shown to the moment in Ruby can be easily achieved with navigation properties and lazy loading (the links I've provided in the first comment).

Comment: So can u write how it can be achieved with navigation properties? Because i didnt find it there.

Comment: `var country = await _context.Country.Include(c => c.Towns).FindAsync(countryId);  var towns = country.Towns;` or with lazy loading enabled:  `var country = await _context.Country.FindAsync(countryId); var towns = country.Towns;`

Comment: Well, that's quite nice. I didn't know that and that's what i looking for. On your navigation properties link is how to setup relationship, but not how to work with LINQ like that.
Then second example should look like this?
```var town = await _context.Town.Include(c => c.Country).Include(c => c.Continent).(FindAsync(TownId);

var country = town.country.continent;```

Comment: The second link is explaining how to use them (i focused  on navogations part cause it was the most similar to what you have described).

Comment: in ef core it is `ThenInclude` for nested properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF supports navigation properties out of the box, so in simple situations you don't need joins. Also you can use lazy loading if you want to. See more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) and [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/querying-data#include-related-data) for example.

In your case if you have correctly setup relations between entities you can translate

```
@country = Country.find(params[:id])
@towns = @country.towns
```

Into:

```
var country = await _context.Country.Include(c => c.Towns).FindAsync(countryId); 
// or await _context.Country.Include(c => c.Towns).FirstAsync(c => c.Id == countryId) 
var towns = country.Towns;
```

Or with lazy loading enabled:

```
var country = await _context.Country.FindAsync(countryId); 
var towns = country.Towns;
```

The second snippet:

```
@town = Town.find(params[:id])
@continent = @town.country.continent
```

Can be translated to:

```
var town = await _context.Town
     .Include(t => t.Country)
     .ThenInclude(c => c.Continent)
     .FindAsync(TownId); 
var country = town.Country.Continent;
```

Comment: Thanks that's that i was looking for.

Comment: Just one last question, how many queries to db generate last example? One? Or its divided by number of includes + find ?

Comment: @Anubix it will generate one query, you can enable logging in EF core and it you will able to see the queries.

Comment: can we also use lazy loading for the last example?

Comment: @cikatomo yes, but note that it can lead to poor performance (especially in case of one-to-many or many-to-many relationships)